Find criteria if a graph is not perfect
A graph is  perfect if the clique number and the chromatic number is the same for every induced subgraph of the graph.
A polynomial-time algorithm exists for determining if a graph is perfect. Currently, Mathematica does not seem to offer a function for identifying perfect graphs. (Cornuéjols G, Liu X, Vuskovic K. A polynomial algorithm for recognizing perfect graphs[C]//44th Annual IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science, 2003. Proceedings. IEEE, 2003: 20-27.)
Fortunately, IGraphM includes a function called IGperfectQ. According to its documentation, IGperfectQ utilizes the strong perfect graph theorem: it checks that neither the graph nor its complement contains an odd-length hole. However, the documentation does not provide further justification or additional details, such as identifying an odd hole or an odd antihole if one exists.
For example, the following graph is not perfect. We may to need to find a hole or an anti-hole.
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5,
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 9,
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
  4 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 
  5 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
  6 \[UndirectedEdge] 13, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 14, 
  7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 14, 
  8 \[UndirectedEdge] 15, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 16, 
  9 \[UndirectedEdge] 16, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 
  10 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 
  10 \[UndirectedEdge] 18, 11 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 
  12 \[UndirectedEdge] 13, 12 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 
  13 \[UndirectedEdge] 20, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 21, 
  14 \[UndirectedEdge] 15, 14 \[UndirectedEdge] 21, 
  15 \[UndirectedEdge] 21, 15 \[UndirectedEdge] 22, 
  16 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 16 \[UndirectedEdge] 22, 
  17 \[UndirectedEdge] 23, 18 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 
  18 \[UndirectedEdge] 20, 18 \[UndirectedEdge] 23, 
  19 \[UndirectedEdge] 20, 20 \[UndirectedEdge] 24, 
  21 \[UndirectedEdge] 24, 22 \[UndirectedEdge] 23, 
  22 \[UndirectedEdge] 24, 23 \[UndirectedEdge] 24}, 
 GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"]
IGPerfectQ[G1]


Do you really need to specify the coordinates to 14 significant digits?  Really?  Are you aware of statements like Range[24]?  Do you need to show the graph embedding at all to ask your question?

I have changed it. Thanks.
